# how to limit threads in weblogic for spring mvc request only

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, weblogic, workmanagers

I am using the weblogic 11g application server to run my spring MVC application. I want to limit the number of threads, calling a request on Spring controller. How can i configure this in weblogic.

I have used the weblogic workmanager's max-threads-constraint to limit the number of threads created for a servlet but in case of spring it's just a one dispatcher servlet so how can we achieve the same with spring mvc application?